# Angular 2 Slider example won't slide

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to replicate the simple Angular Material slider in [this documentation example](https://material.angular.io/components/component/slider) by following its Plunker code.

But my slider won't slide. I can only get it to jump to the clicked position. But it won't click and drag.

I keep looking at the Plunker code trying to find what I'm missing. When I examine and compare my resulting page with the example in Chrome Developer tool I don't see the "md-slider-sliding" class appear in my  element as it does in the example. Somehow I'm not generating or catching that event. I hope I'm showing all relevant code needed to diagnose. (I don't post many questions so please edit to improve if necessary.)

**app-module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Slider lab 1!';
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<md-slider></md-slider>
```

**app.component.css**

```
md-slider {
    width: 300px;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MaterialLab1</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Comment: could you create a plunkr with your code

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Very surprising and dumb little bug. I had no idea that import order matters. I've never seen such a thing in my life! I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that import order matters in the @NgModule. With MaterialModule.forRoot() coming first, the slider won't slide. Putting it last makes it work correctly. Who knew!

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot() // If this comes first, slider won't slide!
]
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XzmOya9Plzyc4317vZbE?p=preview)